# Can anyone help me understand why my transaction won't confirm

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, confirmations, unconfirmed-transactions

https://blockchain.info/tx/23bddd7a323f5e772d4e3cb24c1c0687c8fcfa79066a0986082a8c101f1ce648?show_adv=true
I have a high transaction fee, and not double spending. Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't think that is a high fee: https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ This site suggests it will take 5 to 240 minutes.

Comment: 44.2 satoshi per byte was not a "high fee" yesterday. Yesterday around the time that you posted you would have needed to pay about 1.5 - 2 times that to get into the first block.

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is confirmed now. The blockchain link shows it took 214 minutes to be confirmed.